# Input number jquery , anteponer código de pais

Tags: jquery, html

De que forma puedo anteponer el código de país mientras escribo en el input, con la funcion que tengo al escribir siempre me antepone el codigo, pero me borra lo que escribo, es posible que cuando escriba me anteponga el código pero sin borrar lo que escribo?

```
<input type="text"  id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="celular" maxlength="14">



 $( "#celular" ).focus(function() {
  $("#celular").val("+569");
});
```

Edite la pregunta, como puedo hacer para que el usuario no borre el código del input ?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo hacer otro campo de texto que guarde la lada del país, si no tendrás que agregar un sin fin de validaciones para que tu clave no se borre del input, pero que a la ves te permita agregar el teléfono sin que tu clave se afecte.

Comment: Solo vasto con poner **unbind** y ya estuvo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta que te doy es cambiar el evento **keypress** por **focus** y asi cuando el focus este en el input agrege el codigo y seguido puedas escribir el numero, Suerte

```js
$( "#celular" ).focus(function() {
  $("#celular").val("+569");
  $("#celular").unbind();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="celular">
```

Comment: Eso no funcionará, porque cuando te salgas del input, y regreses nuevamente, el texto que se haya escrito se sobreescribirá por el valor que le agregues en el evento focus. No por nada en cualquier página de registro que pida clave de país lo pone en un campo separado.

Comment: Lo acabo de actualizar ahora si te invito a que lo ejecutes de nuevo

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario borra la clave del país después de haberse ejecutado el evento? o ¿Qué tal si esa clave la genera de manera dinámica en base a un select de países, y el usuario decida a última hora cambiar el país y se tenga que cambiar la clave sin que el usuario tenga que hacerlo? Tal ves me estoy llendo muy lejos y la solución para el OP es solo la que pones en tu respuesta, pero algo que he aprendido desarrollando software es a considerar todos los casos, e imaginar que tus clientes son inexpertos en computación y necesitan que les des la mano todo el tiempo que usando tu sistema/página.